# endomorphisms problem, first year of college linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Let f,g be 2 endomophisms on V(n=dimV>=2) such that

$$f\circ g+a f+a g=0  $$
Show that :
a)
$$f\circ g=g\circ f$$
b)
$$rg(f)=rg(g)$$
c)for n and  a given, give an example of f and g bijective endomorphisms.

Comment: I have tried basic operations like substracting, adding or composing with one of the endomorphisms, but havent gotten to a relevant result.@PJK

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false when $a=0$, since $f\circ g = 0$ does not imply $g\circ f =0$.

If $a\neq 0$, then the relation can be written as $(a^{-1} f + I) \circ (a^{-1} g + I) = I$, where $I$ is the identity. That does imply $(a^{-1} g + I) \circ (a^{-1} f + I) = I$, and from here conclude that $f\circ g = g \circ f$.